# C# elastic search exact text match with nest

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am using latest c# elastic search NEST library.
I am trying to search with exact text match, but currently it is working searching 
for subset match. I want to do exact match.
Following is my code snippet:

---

```
public User GetUserByUsername(string username)
    {
        var client = new ElasticConnectionManager(this.configuration).GetClient(Constant.IndexUsers);

        var searchResponse = client.Search<User>(s => s                
            .Query(q => q
            .Bool(bq => bq                
            .Filter(f => f.Term(t => t.Username, username))
            .Must(mt=>mt.Term(t2=> t2.Username, username)))));

        //.Must(bs => bs.Term(t => t.Username, username))
        if (searchResponse.Documents.Count > 0)
            return searchResponse.Documents.First();
        else
            return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is applying analyzers mandatory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the match_phrase query for exact text match. Your query should be similar to the following:

```
    var searchResponse = client.Search<User>(s => s
            .Query(q => q
            .MatchPhrase(m => m
            .Field(f => f.Username)
            .Query(username))));
```

Comment: Nope, its also doing partial search. Means suppose I have 3 username "abc1@xyz.com", "abc2@xyz.com" and "abc3@xyz.com". If I provide "abc" as input its giving all 3 usrename  in search result.

Comment: This is not the correct answer. For example, if my username was "Lou" then I had another name, "Mary Lou," they would both be selected when I search for "Lou" with the above code.